# Log4J pass logger to helper class

Tags: log4j

if I have two classes with one logger each. Each logger has one appender to its own logfile.

Now each class calls one helper class (both classes call the same helper class) and within the helper class I want to make some logging. How can I write the logs from the helper class to its corresponding logfile?

The only way I thought about is to pass the instance of the logger to the helper class (or the name of the logger). But isn't there a better way to do that? Up to now I declare one new logger inside the helper class, but then the logs will not go to the right appender.

Hopefully you understand my question.

Many greetings,
Hauke